# Python script using subprocess run has different output when run directly in Powershell than when run in Jenkins

Tags: python, powershell, jenkins

I have a python script that runs a git command `git log --pretty=format:%H branch -n 20`

It runs the command using `process = subprocess.Popen(commandLine, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

When we run the git command in powershell directly, or through the python script it works and returns the commits.  When I run the powershell script through Jenkins the command returns the following with no commit data:

```
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
09:12:00  H
```

Any ideas as to why this might happen and how to resolve it?

Edit: It looks like when running through Jenkins the % gets stripped out so the command ends up being `git log --pretty=format:H branch -n 20` and thus the failure.  I'm not sure how to prevent this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shell=True` requests use of the platform-native shell for execution of the given command line.

On Windows, the native shell is `cmd.exe`, where `%` is a [metacharacter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter), which therefore needs *escaping* in order to be interpreted *verbatim*.

- Unfortunately, `cmd.exe` treats `%` *differently* depending on whether it is used in an *interactive* `cmd.exe` session vs. *in a batch file*.

  - With Jenkins *not* in the picture, Python applies *interactive* syntax (via a `cmd /c` call), where `%` characters that aren't part of *variable references* (such as `%USERNAME%`) are *kept as-is*.
- With Jenkins in the picture - for reasons unknown to me, given that the `%` ends up *removed* in your call -  the implication is that ***batch-file* syntax apparently applies *when calling via Jenkins*** , in which case you need to ***double* any `%` chars.** for them to be preserved.

Therefore:

```
# When called via Jenkins.
process = subprocess.Popen(
  commandLine.replace('%', '%%'), 
  shell=True, 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```